# Multiple OR Clauses in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm trying to grab content where id = 3 OR id = 9 OR id = 100... Keep in mind, I can have a few hundred of these ids.

What is the most efficient way to write my query?

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM artists WHERE (id=3 OR id=9 OR .... id-100)"
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
  ....
WHERE id IN (3, 9, 100, ...)
```

Comment: At some point it'd probably be easier to insert the ids into a temporary table and do a join on that. But of course that'd require testing to find out just how many ids would make the table creation overhead worth it.

Comment: How about a sub-query instead of a temp table? `... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)`

Answer (score 11):

You may want to use the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function:

```
... WHERE id IN (3, 9, 100);
```

The `IN()` function syntax:

> **`expr IN (value,...)`**
>
> Check whether a value is within a set of values
>   ...
>
> Returns `1` if `expr` is equal to any of the values in the `IN` list, else returns `0`.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3 etc)
```

And call only the columns you need rather than using `*`!

Answer (score 6):

You can use SQL IN condition

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,5);
```

Answer (score -2):

$sql = "SELECT name FROM artists WHERE id REGEXP *regex-pattern*"

Comment: -1... inefficient if an index exists and assumes the regex pattern can be more efficient (like ranges), which is not a given (i.e. not in the post).