# SQL Syntax for multiple conditions in the same field

Tags: sql, database, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple OR Clauses in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030906/multiple-or-clauses-in-mysql)

I can't seem to find this in the mysql manual:

How do you enter multiple conditions for the same field in a select statement?

e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Is there a way to do this without using this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '1' OR ID = '2' OR ID = '3' OR ID = '4'
```