# Can you shorten the following query?

Tags: sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple OR Clauses in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030906/multiple-or-clauses-in-mysql)

Can you think of a shorter way to write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 5 OR (etc...)
```